# How to call method in file .aj in spring roo project?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

How to call method in file .aj in spring roo project?

e.g. How to call method "Employee.findAllEmployees()" in Employee_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj from method callMethod() in Employee.java?

**file: Employee.java**

```
  1 package com.tap.domain;
  2 
  3 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  4 import java.util.ArrayList;
  5 import java.util.Calendar;
  6 
  7 import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
  8 import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
  9 
 10 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
 11 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 12 import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
 13 import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
 14 import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
 15 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
 16 
 17 @RooJavaBean
 18 @RooToString
 19 @RooJpaActiveRecord
 20 @Component("employee")
 21 public class Employee {
 22 
 23     private long id;
 24 
 25     private String name;
 26 public void callMethod() {
...
...
 30 }
```

**file:Employee_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj**

```
  6 import java.util.List;
  7 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
  8 import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
  9 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
 10 import com.tap.domain.Employee;
 11 
 12 privileged aspect Employee_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord {
 13 
 14     @PersistenceContext
 15     transient EntityManager Employee.entityManager;
...
 27     public static List<Employee> Employee.findAllEmployees() {
 28         return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Employee o", Emplo    yee.class).getResultList();
 29     }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism Roo uses is AspectJ's [inter-type declaration](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html).

Basically: your employee class will have the `findAllEmployees()` method at runtime, so you can just call it:

```
public void callMethod() {
    List<Employee> allEmployees = findAllEmployees();
    // now do something with the employees
}
```